# Picasso detected an unsupported OkHttp on the classpath

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I am using Picasso 2.3.2 and okhttp 1.5.4

Initially I was getting this RTE:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Picasso detected an unsupported OkHttp on the classpath.
To use OkHttp with this version of Picasso, you'll need:
1. com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0 (or newer)
2. com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0 (or newer)
Note that OkHttp 2.0.0+ is supported!
        at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.createDefaultDownloader(Utils.java:246)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.build(Picasso.java:596)
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:473)
```

Then I updated the pom with com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0 (ran mvn clean install, reimported maven in IntelliJ), but the crash still happens.

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

i face same problem.
Must use both `okhttp` and `okhttp-urlconnection`.
I use this three lib. and then it work properly

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

try it. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is here:
https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/541

Must use both okhttp and okhttp-urlconnection, until OkHttp 2.0 final is out.

Comment: it's needed with 2.0 final as well.

Comment: Did you, by any chance find a gradle dependency for the okhttp-urlconnection ?

Comment: for me i am using okhtttp3.i have updated picasso .its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I am Facing same problem. I resolve this issue by using

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
 testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.0.0-RC1'
 compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

i update the version of picasso library and it worked.
refer website for latest version http://square.github.io/picasso/

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```